# Backbone.js Model with 2 parents

Tags: backbone.js, relationships

I would like to create a backbone based page where there are undefined amount of columns and rows in a table-like layout. The 'table' structure and cell data should be saved to the backend.

The simplified models are:

row:

- id
- label

column:

- id
- label

cell:

- rowID
- columnId
- value

in this situation a cell belongs to one row and one column.

If I add rows and columns dynamically how will the cells know what their rowID and columnId is especially in case of a newly added row+column which is not saved yet?

An other question is how I can connect a row of cells to a row object and at the same time a column of cells to a column object?

Thank you in advance, please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

I would forget the concepts of rows and columns and just use index position for your cells.

If you have C columns and R rows, the cell at position Column = 2 and Row = 3 would be at position (3 - 1) * C + 2

This allows you to easily deal with changing numbers of columns and rows.  You can also dynamically recalculate all objects that belong to a row or a column and then create object and row columns.

Comment: this is a good idea, but I have to use the persistent data for other purposes too, in this way knowing which column or which row a given piece of information belongs to is essential.